# A Good Resource (Book, ...) For Literary Techniques/Devices?

Tags: writing, technical, literature, resources, literary-techniques

What's a good book (Or resource) on Literary Techniques/Devices in English Literature?

Answer (score 2):

For rhetorical devices (anaphora, isocolon, chiasmus, metanoia, etc.) I recommend *[Classical English Rhetoric](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_42?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=ward+farnsworth+classical+english+rhetoric&sprefix=ward+farnsworth+classical+english+rhetoric)* by Ward Farnsworth.

For other literary devices (synecdoche, alliteration, prosody, etc.) I recommend *[The Oxford Dictionary of Literary Terms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199208271)* by Chris Baldick.